# Flexbox with three background images centered at same location?

Tags: css, flexbox, background-image

Is it possible while using Flexbox to have three divs with the same background image and two of them being rotated just like the image shows?

The image show my old draft of a website, but I was going by the old way for getting that result. Now I would like to try using only flexbox. The reason I want them to be three separate divs is because I want to be able to place box-shadow on them, without actually updating the original images themselves.

Another issue that I've faced is that they need to expand together, so two of the paper_sheets needs to change it's size depending on the top sheet that contains the page information, like you can see on the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<style>
  main {
    align-items: flex-start;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 480px;
    width: 480px;  
  }
  aside, section {
    padding: 0 1em;
  }
  aside, section, section:before, section:after {
    background: beige;
    border: 1px solid;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  }
  section {
    height: 260px;
    position: relative;
    width: 260px;
  }
  section:after,
  section:before {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  section:after {
    filter: brightness(0.8);
    transform: rotate(3.6deg);
  }
  section:before {
    filter: brightness(0.9);
    transform: rotate(-3.6deg);
  }
  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    margin: 1em 0;
  }
</style>

<main>
  <section>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </section>
  <aside>
    <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </aside>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you, Henrik for your example!

The only thing that I would like to know if you, or anyone else, know of a flexbox validator? Other than selecting/deselecting each attribute using the web developer tools, is there a way to validate the css code regarding flexbox?